# Software installed on root partition or on home partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I am planning to install some big softwares such as Matlab (4GB), Mathematica (4GB) on my Ubuntu partitions.

I was wondering

1. if I installed them on my home
   partition, when I reinstall Ubuntu
   without touching the home partition,
   will the softwares still be runnable
   after reinstallation?
2. what are the advantage and
   disadvantages of installing
   softwares on root partition and of
   on home partition?
3. with your answer to the previous
   questions, what are some reasonable
   plans for the sizes of root
   partition and of home partition?
   Note that I would like to learn
   programming in C, C++, Java, Python,
   Lisp, databases under both Ubuntu
   and Windows, and no games. My laptop
   has around 230 GB, where I plan to
   install both Windows and Ubuntu, and
   reserve 40 GB for Ubuntu (three
   partitions: swap, root and home),
   110 GB for NTFS partition shared
   between the two OSes, 70 GB for
   Windows OS partition, and 10 GB that
   can be added to any of the above
   partitions. I will change my plan
   according to your suggestions.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions in the order you asked them:

1. It depends on how Matlab and Mathematica are distributed; if they are distributed as static binaries, then you should be okay. A static binary has any of the libraries needed by the program compiled into them. Generally, this is not the default for compiled applications, as it leads to extremely large binaries.
2. There really aren't any disadvantages, per say; it depends on the application. If you're installing an application from `apt-get`, Synaptic or from the Ubuntu Software Centre, the application is being installed in your root partition. If you have a static binary that you have downloaded and unpackaged yourself, then your best bet would be to keep it in your home directory. For any scripts or programs I write or install, that are not provided by the Ubuntu repositories, I keep them in a `bin` directory in my home folder. This way, they aren't "polluting" my base system.
3. The size of your root partition really depends on how many applications and libraries you plan on installing from the Ubuntu repositories. Different Linux distributions recommend different sizes. If you allow Ubuntu to automatically partition your drive, with a separate partition for `/home`, the Ubuntu installer will give you a sane layout. C and C++ compilers, Lisp REPLs, Python interpreters and the various databases do not take up much room. The only large compiler is for Java; I believe it weighs in at around 80MB for the JDK (Java Development Kit). As with my answer for your second question, most of the stuff you write, you should keep to your home directory, so you do not pollute the base system. Plus, if you ever upgrade your Ubuntu install, you will not have to worry about accidentally blowing away the directory you keep your projects in. Granted, you run this risk anyways, it will just be easier to keep everything you do in your home directory; that is what it is there for.