# Difference between root and home

Tags: filesystem, home-directory

I download a program from repository and install that. I know we need three partitions for Linux: (1) SWAP, (2) `/` (3), `/home`. Also I know `/home` is like a user profile and `/` is like a operating system profile.

So, we see the conclusion, if I install a program from repository this program belongs to me and not related to operating system. But you know the place of downloaded program is `/usr/bin` and etc  But not in `/home`? `/home` is my profile. Please say where my conclusion is wrong?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/379205/installing-programs-in-root-vs-home-partitions

Comment: You do not **need** them. You **can** have them and much more. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/379205/installing-programs-in-root-vs-home-partitions and also http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/25158/software-installed-on-root-partition-or-on-home-partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The home directories are only for the user's personal data.

I assume you are familiar with Windows. Windows places programs in the Program Files directory (like `/usr/bin`) too, not in the Users directory (like `/home`) . This way all users can use the program. However, settings are usually per user and are stored in the user's home directory.

Comment: thanks I just want to add that I can use ~/bin to install programs http://askubuntu.com/questions/440980/which-file-to-add-to-usr-local-bin-from-a-program-installed-from-source

Answer (score 1):

> So we see the conclusion

Not, only you.

> if I install a program from repository this program belongs to me and
>   not related to Operating System

The Operative Systems is the one who runs the applications. You only install and use it, but it *is* "related" to the OS.