# How to install package without sudo?

Tags: sudo

I am trying to do this http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Advanced/headless_rendering.html It needs me to install this `sudo apt-get install libosmesa6-dev` but I am on a shared workstation with no access to `sudo`. Is there a way to install the package without sudo? And to install to my home directory?

Comment: No, there are no way to use `apt-get` without `sudo` or being the `root` user. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25158/software-installed-on-root-partition-or-on-home-partition) for more.

Comment: Also, installing a 3D headless rendering engine on a "shared" workstation, where you are NOT the System Administrator, is just rude.

Comment: thank you. Was hoping for a non rude solution e.g. conda create -n env; conda install lebosmesa6-dev but i guess i need to ask the admin to install it for me

Comment: Because packages install programs to directories owned by `root` you need to use `sudo` to install them. You are correct your system administrator can have the program installed for you but chances are he (or she) makes big bucks to tell you "no" and tell his boss how he saved the company by doing so. Sorry to say that in most companies the way things are done are not always the right way. Not that I'm agreeing that the program you want is right for your company. Not sure how you've been a member for 5 years and made 881 points and don't know `sudo` ins and outs yet... But there ya go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install a package without root access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access)