# How to organize files in linux?

Tags: files

I am super new to linux (1 day experience) and i have a root partition along with home partition now i want to know that like in windows we either can by default install application to program files or custom directory so in linux or ubuntu or zorin should i install it in root also the root partition is smaller compared to home.

Comment: You may find [this questions and its two answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379205/installing-programs-in-root-vs-home-partitions) useful. Also take a look at this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25158/software-installed-on-root-partition-or-on-home-partition) that asks the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can but you will need to abandon normal installation method and use source installs. The way to install 3rd party apps is by installing in `/opt/` for global software or in `/home/$USER/` in a private directory.

BUT I would advice against it and use the normal install methods. Linux is NOT Windows so please do not attempt to copy how Windows works. Linux by default is designed to be multi-user with an administrator account to maintain the system. The directory structure is setup to accommodate that.

Each file in Linux has a place to go to otherwise you will need to install the same file multiple times (like Windows does) wasting lots of disk space.

> should i install it in root also the root partition is smaller compared to home.

A normal desktop install not using snaps needs about 20Gb. If you need more space deleting snaps and installing the normal version of that software is a good way to save up on space.

Comment: " I would advice against it and use the normal install methods." +1000

Comment: Should i then increase partitition size of /root?

Comment: That would be better yes. As stated: I have used an ssd for a long time now and I never ever got over 20Gb (I am not using snaps; I delete those and install the regular version).